# I accidentally removed myself from sudoers, how can I fix this?

Tags: sudo, users

I have one admin account and recently I have accidentally added myself to a single group (`usermod -G` without `-a`).

So, I am not in the sudoers file any more. However, it is not possible to log in to root by default on Ubuntu. Do I [reset](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword) the password for root during the boot process?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

No need to reset root password (well, technically, Ubuntu's root does not even *have* a password). Do this:

- Reboot your PC
- In Grub's OS selection screen, choose "Ubuntu xxxx - *recovery mode*"
- Now you have a console with root privileges. Add your user back to `sudo` group:

  ```
    usermod -a -G sudo youruser
  ```

The shell might reply that it cannot do it because the file system in mounted in read-only. To remount your fs in read-write: `mount -o remount,rw /`

- That will be enough for sudo. But its suggested you also re-add yourself to other default administrative groups. You can reboot, logon normally and use GUI:

`Menu > Administration > Users and Groups > Advanced Settings > User Privileges` or `Account Type (Change...) > Administrative`

- Or use this command:

  ```
    sudo usermod -a -G adm,cdrom,plugdev,lpadmin,sambashare youruser
  ```

Notes:

- The `sudo` group used to be the `admin` group prior to Ubuntu 12.04. If you're on anything older, replace the group `sudo` with the group `admin` in the above commands.
- Starting from Ubuntu 20.04, the `fuse` group does not exist anymore. It allowed regular users to access `/dev/fuse` using `fusemount`, i.e., to mount FUSE filesystems. But [since Debian 8](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemGroups#fuse) `/dev/fuse` is already world-writeable by default.

***Important Note:***
The default set of groups for what is considered an "Administrator" role
changes over time, as some groups become obsolete or irrelevant (such as `tape` or `floppy`), are removed, renamed or re-organized, or are created in your system only when related packages are installed (`sambashare`, `virtualbox`, `www_data`). So in a few years `adm`, `cdrom` or `lpadmin` might not exist (that is, *if* they still do!).

Besides, some features that currently use groups for filesystem-based permissions might change to another access permission mechanism, such as `udev`, PAM, AppArmor, SELinux, etc.

So the only way to get an updated list of groups is... to check your current system! Create a new temporary Administrator user using the GUI, or do a fresh install in a VM, and see which groups the user is assigned to by default.

Comment: That's what I figured out myself. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Glad you found out. And hope you didnt "reset" root's password while trying. In Ubuntu root is a disabled account (=no password), for a good reason. Keep it that way. You will still be able to use sudo, `sudo su`, recovery mode, etc. Disabling root's password only mean you can not *login* as root in a login shell, which is a very good security measure.

Comment: Hypothetically ... What if one had disabled GRUB recovery mode by uncommenting `GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"` in `/etc/default/grub`. What would one do?

Comment: @sudoman: boot using a CD/USB live session, mount the original root partition, edit its `/etc/default/grub`(or directly the config files at `/boot/grub`) and update/reinstall grub. Basically the same procedures as if you had lost grub as the boot manager (when installing windows, for example)

Comment: On Mint 20, I get `usermod: group 'fuse' does not exist`, so I just left it out.

Comment: @CoderGuy123 thanks for pointing that out! Did some research and added a note about it.