# How could I have dropped out of sudoers?

Tags: sudo

I started to receive a message

```
dims is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

about myself.

How could this happen?

The suspicious command I made was creating group "advanced" and adding myself to it.

```
addgroup advanced
usermod -G advanced dims
```

Could this break my sudo rights?

Comment: Post `groups` command output, this will print `dims` groups.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel While I think the questions are related, I'm not so sure this is a dupe. IMO Dims is asking *how* or *why* this happened, not how to fix it. The answer here wouldn't fit on the other question either, which is a strong suggestion they are not duplicates.

Comment: Related: [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)

Comment: @Seth I see - I was noticing that other question has an answer also mentioning the other groups - but it's more a related, and not strictly relevant to the "how comes" question (but very relevant to the "how to fix" question)

Comment: You might have dropped out of other groups too, see: http://askubuntu.com/a/59367/260447

Comment: This is why it's best to avoid `usermod` and use `adduser`: `adduser <username> <groupname>`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After

```
usermod -G advanced dims
```

the user `dims` is only a member of the group `advanced` but not of any other group. So as he isn't a member of the group `admin` or `sudo` he is no longer allowed to use `sudo`.

To just add a user to another group you need to use the `-a` switch to `usermod`, like

```
usermod -a -G advanced dims
```